# How to use .length of an array value

Tags: c#

I have a variable `result` which contains a JSON object:

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PullRequestModel>(responseData);
```

I would like to use `for` loop over `result` as:

```
@for (var key = 0; key < result.value.length; key++)
{
            
}
```

But C# thinks `.length` is part of the PullRequestModel, and the code is not working.

How do I get around this problem?

This is the `PullRequestModel`

```
namespace TestApp.Model.PullRequestModel
{
    public class Avatar
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompletionOptions
    {
        public string mergeCommitMessage { get; set; }
        public bool deleteSourceBranch { get; set; }
        public bool squashMerge { get; set; }
        public string mergeStrategy { get; set; }
        public bool triggeredByAutoComplete { get; set; }
        public List<object> autoCompleteIgnoreConfigIds { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreatedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Iterations
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastMergeCommit
    {
        public string commitId { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastMergeSourceCommit
    {
        public string commitId { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastMergeTargetCommit
    {
        public string commitId { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public Repository repository { get; set; }
        public WorkItems workItems { get; set; }
        public SourceBranch sourceBranch { get; set; }
        public TargetBranch targetBranch { get; set; }
        public Statuses statuses { get; set; }
        public SourceCommit sourceCommit { get; set; }
        public TargetCommit targetCommit { get; set; }
        public MergeCommit mergeCommit { get; set; }
        public CreatedBy createdBy { get; set; }
        public Iterations iterations { get; set; }
    }

    public class MergeCommit
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string visibility { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastUpdateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Repository
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reviewer
    {
        public string reviewerUrl { get; set; }
        public int vote { get; set; }
        public bool hasDeclined { get; set; }
        public bool isRequired { get; set; }
        public bool isFlagged { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public bool isContainer { get; set; }
        public List<VotedFor> votedFor { get; set; }
    }

    public class PullRequestModel
    {
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceBranch
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceCommit
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Statuses
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class TargetBranch
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class TargetCommit
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public Repository repository { get; set; }
        public int pullRequestId { get; set; }
        public int codeReviewId { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public CreatedBy createdBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime closedDate { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string sourceRefName { get; set; }
        public string targetRefName { get; set; }
        public string mergeStatus { get; set; }
        public bool isDraft { get; set; }
        public string mergeId { get; set; }
        public LastMergeSourceCommit lastMergeSourceCommit { get; set; }
        public LastMergeTargetCommit lastMergeTargetCommit { get; set; }
        public LastMergeCommit lastMergeCommit { get; set; }
        public List<Reviewer> reviewers { get; set; }
        public List<object> labels { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public CompletionOptions completionOptions { get; set; }
        public bool supportsIterations { get; set; }
        public DateTime completionQueueTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class VotedFor
    {
        public string reviewerUrl { get; set; }
        public int vote { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public bool isContainer { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItems
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }


}
```

This is the cause of the whole problem, if anyone is curious:

```
@if(result ==  null)
{
    <p> No pull requests found</p>

}
else
{
    @foreach (var item in result.value)
    {
        <div class="accordion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="tab1">
            <label class="accordion-label" for="tab1">  @item.title </label>
            <div class="accordion-content">   
            <WorkItems PersonalAccessToken="@PersonalAccessToken" WorkItemUrl="@item._links.workItems.href"></WorkItems>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The above code works (it's a Blazor app) I loop trough all Pull requests and show associated Work Items for the PR.

But In order to crete a simple accordion, the I must increment `id="tab1">` because in each loop, so my idea was to ditch `@foreach` and use `@for` loop, so I can make use of the `key` to increment the value of `id="tab1">`

Hope it makes sense

Comment: please provide a [mcve] on how all this ties together

Comment: Post your `PullRequestModel` class. If C# says there's an error, there's an error

Comment: Please provide the `PullRequestModel` class

Comment: its also `Length` if it is an array.

Comment: @ale91 Added, it's just a JSON object converted into C# model

Comment: `result` is a `PullRequestModel` instance. For your code to compile it would need to have a `Value` property with a weirdly cased `length` property. That `Value` is certainly not an array, as `Array.Length` starts with a capital L

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the model

Comment: `List<>` has no `Length` property, much less a `length`. It has a `Count` property

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to use for loop over result" when result is just a single object?

Comment: All of this is *much* more confusing than it needs to be because you've called both the namespace and the class `PullRequestModel` - and because you're not following .NET naming conventions, and because you've provided nearly 200 lines of code with the important bit right in the middle, instead of a [mcve] which would make the whole thing much clearer. (And your property is of type `List<Value>`, not an array as per your question title.)

Comment: @JonSkeet actually `result` contains many Pull Requests that I have to use foreach to display, but the reason and where the error comes from is now shown in my updated question

Comment: Sorry for all the mess, I am just a beginner and I thought it might be a common error

Comment: @Displayname: If you'd used `foreach` to start with, it would have just worked: `foreach (var item in result.value)` would compile. I'd still strongly recommend fixing all the rest though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mentioned in the update, you can see I am using `foreach` and it works. I just wanted to have an incremental key so I can update the id of my div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PullRequestModel>(responseData);
@for (var key = 0; key < result.value.Count; key++)
{
            
}
```

*List<>* exposes the **Count** property not **Length** property.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you are deserializing a single object and not an enumerable type. Please try using the following if you want to return something to loop through:

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PullRequestModel>>(responseData);
@for (var key = 0; key < result.Count; key++)
{
            
}
```

Count is a property of of the List object in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but why should I change `<PullRequestModel>` to list?

Comment: In your code, the result object is a single item; if you're trying to deserialize a json response into a collection of objects to be iterated over, declaring them as a list of a particular type is a logical choice.

Comment: @work89: It isn't clear because the model code is so long (and because both the namespace and the class are called `PullRequestModel`), but the class `PullRequestModel` genuinely does have a property called `value` which is a list.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see you are correct. In that case ale91's answer is likely the closest to what the question is looking for.